# NavigationView menu confuses FragmentPagerAdapter with 3 Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library, fragmentpageradapter

I have prepared [a simple test case](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/MyViewPager) for my problem at GitHub.

In an app with DrawerLayout I display a [PagerFragment](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/MyViewPager/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/myviewpager) which uses a custom FragmentPagerAdapter to swipe between 3 other support fragments: [MovesFragment](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/MyViewPager/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/myviewpager), [GameFragment](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/MyViewPager/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/myviewpager) and [ChatFragment](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/MyViewPager/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/myviewpager):

[image: app screenshot]

This works well and I am able to swipe horizontally through the 3 Fragments.

However when I use the NavigationView menu to display another game with -

```
private void showGame(int gid) {
    PagerFragment f = PagerFragment.newInstance(gid);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.root, f)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Then I end up with an empty screen and the new game is seemingly not displayed (only the `gid=2` is correctly mentioned in the app title):

[image: problem screenshot]

My custom FragmentPagerAdapter is very simple with -

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int mGid;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int gid) {
        super(fm);
        mGid = gid;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return MovesFragment.newInstance(mGid);
            case 2: return ChatFragment.newInstance(mGid);
            default: return GameFragment.newInstance(mGid);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here please, how to pass and display the `gid` (aka game id) into the 3 fragments embedded in a ViewPager?

Comment: Your `CustomPagerAdapter` inside `PagerFragment` should be instantiated using `getChildFragmentManager()`, not `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`. Possibly some issue with conflicting tags, since that's how `FragmentPagerAdapter` tracks its `Fragment`s.

Comment: Thank you, changing to `getChildFragmentManager()` has helped. I am not sure what do you mean by tags, should I somehow set them inside of MovesFragment, GameFragment, ChatFragment classes?

Comment: No, you don't want to mess with the `Fragment` tags in a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. As mentioned, that's how it tracks its `Fragment`s, and it creates those tags using the `ViewPager`'s ID and the `Fragment`'s position, by default. Since the `ViewPager` always has the same ID, and your `Fragment`s are using the same positions, it caused some sort of issue when the second game's `Fragment`s were attached to the same `FragmentManager` as the first's. Since you're now using each game `Fragment`'s own child `FragmentManager`, there's no longer multiple `Fragment`s with the same tag attached to one.